# js products list doesnt get .length

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So using JS to create 'products'

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    var products = [
                    @{
            bool addComma = false;
            foreach (UMACS.Bradmount.Models.QBProductRecord product in Model.AllProducts)
            {
                if (addComma)
                {
                                <text> @Html.Raw(",") </text>
                }

                            <text> @Html.Raw(string.Format("{{ value: \"{0} ({1})\", label: \"{0} ({1})\", desc: \"{1}\", prodid: \"{2}\" }}", product.ProductCode.Stripped(), product.ProductName.Stripped(), product.Id)) </text>

                addComma = true;
            }
                    }
                    ];
```

So this products something like:

```
//                        {
//                            value: "CARSLI5",
//                            label: "CARSLI5",
//                            desc: "Carrots Sliced 5kg",
//                            prodid: "43"
//                        },
//                        {
//                            value: "CARBAT5",
//                            label: "CARBAT5",
//                            desc: "Carrots Baton 5kg",
//                            prodid: "24"
//                        }
//                    ];
```

Then later on I am trying to say

```
self.selectedProductId = ko.computed(function() {
                        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                            if (products[i].label == self.selectedProduct()) {
                                return products[i].prodid;
                            }
                        }       
                        return "0";
```

where products.length is saying products does not exist? any ideas as to why?

Comment: Your products list contains Javascript and HTML? Seems . . . crazy.

Comment: if products is an object, it doesn't have a length property

Comment: If products is defined as you say then it has a length property (http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/Y6HUU/). My guess is there is more to this problem

Comment: It sounds like the problem isn't that `products` doesn't have a length property, but that `products` does not exist. What is the actual error you are getting, and what do you mean by "later on"?

Comment: Any particular reason the pasted in example of your products array is commented out?  Also what does the <text> tag do?

Answer (score 1):

A JS list should look like `var list = [["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]];` with `[]` not `{}`

`list.length` will give 3

So on `list[0].length` gives 2

Comment: The OP is surrounding the `products` array in square brackets (the `@{}` is a server side tag, I'm guessing ASP)